# Hover over menu element to show submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a **menu** that has a **sub-menu** (Not a dropdown) that slides in from left-to-right, when mouseover; and right-to-left when mouseout.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z40xo01d/4/

Two vertical menus side-by-side:

**HTML code:**

```
<aside class="nav-container">

  <!--Main Navigation Structure-->
    <ul id="nav-main">
      <a href="#"><li class="fa fa-home fa-2x" id="home"></li><br/></a>
      <a href="#"><li class="fa fa-folder fa-2x" id="projects"></li><br/></a>
      <a href="#"><li class="fa fa-user fa-2x" id="about"></li><br/></a>
      <a href="#"><li class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" id="contact"></li><br/></a>

      <!--Additional Navigation Buttons-->
      <div id="nav-additionals">
          <a href="#"><p class="fa fa-cogs fa-s" id="settings"></p></a>
          <a href="#"><p class="fa fa-question fa-s" id="about"></p></a>
      </div>
    </ul>

    <!--Projects submenu-->
    <ul id="proj_menu">
      <a href="#"><li class="icon-python"></li></a>
      <a href="#"><li class="icon-java-bold"></li></a>
      <a href="#"><li class="icon-csharp"></li></a>
      <a href="#"><li class="icon-cplusplus"></li></a>
      <a href="#"><li class="icon-javascript"></li></a>
      <a href="#"><li class="icon-html"></li></a>
      <a href="#"><li class="icon-ruby"></li></a>
      <a href="#"><li class="icon-php"></li></a>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

**JQuery code:**

```
<script>
  $("document").ready(function(){

    //hides menu when loaded
    $("#proj_menu").hide();

    //shows and hides projects sub menu
    $("#projects").mouseover(function(){

      //if it is hovered SHOW
      if($("#projects").is(":hover")){
          $("#proj_menu").show();
      }
      //if it is not hovered HIDE
      else if($("#projects").not(":hover")){
          $("proj_menu").hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @JeremyRajan JSFifddle on post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

**Updated:**

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/z40xo01d/10/)</kbd>

```
$("#projects").hover(function(){
    $("#proj_menu").animate({
        left: '120px'
    });
});

$("#proj_menu").hover(function(){},function(){
    $("#proj_menu").animate({
        left: '-170px'
    });
});
```

Comment: Needs some tweeks but pointed me in the right direction, Thank you!!! Saved me some time:)

Answer (score 0):

add below css class  to the proj_menu

```
.menu2col li {
    width: 155px !important;
    float: left !important;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
    /*display:inline-block !important;*/
}
```

hope it may works..